# How to setup a good development environment for sharepoint 2013

Tags: environment

We have the exact same issue. We have 6 developers, single sharepoint solution, 1 big server. We tried to create 6 web apps but still when they deploy it overwrites other developer's changes as they have not checkedin their changes yet. How to fix this? Amit Amitloh@gmail.com